# In the UK's equivalent of America's Miranda Rights, what does the second part of the first sentence mean?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, expressions, definite-articles

In the United States, the rights of an arrested citizen are known as "Miranda rights." After the police representative who makes an arrest tells the suspect what charge or charges are being leveled against him or her, the representative is obligated to read aloud the rights afforded them by law. A fairly accurate version of "Miranda" is as follows:

> You have the right to remain silent. If you give up that right, anything you say can and will be used against you in a court of law. You have the right to have an attorney present during questioning. If you cannot afford a lawyer, one will be appointed to you free of charge. Do you understand these rights as I have read them to you?

In the UK, a similar statement is read to a person accused of a crime, once the charges are leveled against him or her. One version is as follows:

> You do not have to say anything, but it may harm your defence if you do not mention when questioned something you later rely on in court. Anything you do say may be given in evidence.

Frankly--and this may be Yankee bias, I think Miranda is much clearer and easier to understand than its UK analog. I suppose I could--and perhaps should--research the meaning of the statement's first sentence. I am certainly willing to do that, but I think giving EL&U readers, who may already have a better understanding than I, a chance to enlighten me is well within the rules of the site.

I find the use of the word *it* to be partly to blame for my confusion. I also wonder *how* specifically not saying something at the arrest could work against the accused when in court they rely on what was *not* said during the arrest, after having been read their rights.

Any legal minds who spot any inaccuracies in my question: Feel free to amend it.

Comment: ELU is not the place for questions on law or jurisprudential practice. So your "how" question is off-topic. How is the "dummy" or "existential" *it* not clear? "It may harm your defence if you do not do X" seems perfectly clear.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: We may need to agree to disagree agreeably. (I'm willing to.). My question is primarily about meaning, not the finer points of jurisprudence. Yes, perhaps my use of the word "how" was ill advised, yet I think the UK analog could be made clearer with different wording. E.g., "You may choose to remain silent during questioning. Doing so, however, could hurt you if your case goes to trial, and only there do you reveal potentially exculpatory evidence you failed to mention during questioning."  (Admittedly, my use of "exculpatory" is a bit of a stretch. Nevertheless . . . )

Comment: @rhetorician The US version isn't clear at all—I've always had a problem with it. *Can and* ***will*** is ridiculous as far as I'm concerned. Either *can* or *will* on its own would make sense, but *can **and** will* doesn't make any sense to me. Which is it? Is it *certain* to be used against your or is it only *possible* that it will be used against you? If I were read the US Miranda rights, my response would be that I don't understand what's being said. The only thing I actually understand is that I shouldn't say anything without an attorney.

Comment: I wonder if the OP, who is gathering a gratifying number of close votes, realises how much it burns Brits when their society, practices, etc, are viewed as inferior copies of the US ones? By Americans, needless to say.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I'm sorry for offending you. I do not view Brit "society, practices, etc." to be inferior. My question concerns a relatively small part of Britain's system of jurisprudence. As for "analog," the American Miranda rights could just as easily be considered an analog of the British. Moreover, I think I am justified in saying the US version is perhaps easier to understand than the British version, although a commenter above thinks differently, finding Mranda to be unclear. Touché!

Comment: There is no obligation to inform a suspect of Miranda rights.  Statements made before the suspect is informed of these rights are not generally admissible as evidence.

Answer (score 4):

This is really about law, not English, but easy enough.

In US law, not only is a defendant allowed to remain silent, but the fact that he/she remained silent cannot be used against them at a trial. For example, at the time of trial, if the defendant claims they were with someone when the crime happened, the prosecution is not allowed to say "well why didn't you say that when police asked you where you were?".

In UK law that last part isn't true. The defendant is allowed to remain silent, but at trial the prosecution is allowed to ask why they didn't say where they were when questioned by police.

"It" is the dummy "it" used in phrases like "it is raining".

Comment: Your answer helps me a bit. Thanks for providing an example. Thanks too for 'splaining the difference between Miranda and its UK analog. Don